# I have a problem with hosting my discord bot on heroku. It's writen in discord.py async

Tags: asynchronous, discord.py

The whole code is working, but the problem is token. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/571302596686643200/605511072828620810/unknown.png 
This worked several months before but I don't know why it's not working now.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/571302596686643200/605510911293128773/unknown.png
This is the error I'm getting in the heroku logs.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/571302596686643200/605511779610787840/unknown.png

I'm sorry if I did not explain well, I really dont know how to explain this lol

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the `os` module? That looks like the error according to the logs.

Comment: I did now, the bot went online but nothing is working.

Comment: Need more details - what do you mean by nothing's working? @Frelpnun

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import os

token = os.environ.get("BOT_TOKEN")
client.run(token)
```

EDIT:

`bot.run` to `client.run`